# Fitting image into PDF using ITEXT

Tags: java, image, pdf, itext

Hi im having some problems to add the image into the PDF using the itextPDF...

i have more than 10.000 images scanned from original paper in past years, and different sizes/pixels

when i add image into pdf using

img.scaleAbsolute(823,640)
or
img.scaleToFit(823,640)

doesnt change the result of each image, for example this ones:

First One 654 is the correct one that fit perfectly in the pdf PAGE, the original tiff image has  (2048 x 2929)

here image -> [image]

here is the second one 9436 that original tiff image has (1470 x 2057)

[image]

look the MARGIN of the pdf in the first and in the second one...

there is a way to make EVERY  image like the 654, no matter the original size??

thanks, aprreciate any idea, or i will have to open all the image in paint and edit it :(

Comment: Solved it using the Comment of Franz Ebner from here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120775/itext-image-resize

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solved for me:

```
//if you would have a chapter indentation
int indentation = 0;
//whatever
Image image = coolPic;

float scaler = ((document.getPageSize().getWidth() - document.leftMargin()
               - document.rightMargin() - indentation) / image.getWidth()) * 100;

image.scalePercent(scaler);
```

from @Franz Ebner

[iText Image Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120775/itext-image-resize)

Comment: but the image whatever it comes ,it is getting compressed.how to scale the image properly ,so it should appear proper

Answer (score 32):

I know it's an old question, but I was looking for it myself and I've found:

```
Image image = ...;
image.scaleToFit(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), PageSize.A4.getHeight());
```

found it useful enough to share here.

Comment: Thanks a great solution :)

Comment: Thanks for saving me in 2017.

Comment: If you use margins, you have to substract them from the page width/height otherwise the image will be cut. You can get them from the document (see the validated answer).