# How to make pdf image fit the whole screen android

Tags: java, android, itext, pdf-generation

I'm using [this depo git](https://github.com/sbpinilla/ImgtoPdf/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sergio/imgtopdf/PdfUtils.java) application that allows you to capture or choose images and save them in a pdf document. It's working great except the image saved does not fit the whole screen.

[image]

So I tried changing theses numbers `Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 38, 38, 50, 38);` or `image.setBorderWidth(15);`

```
(documentRect.getWidth() - image.getScaledWidth()) / 2,
(documentRect.getHeight() - image.getScaledHeight()) / 2);
```

but no luck...

Furthermore the author didn't not use any `imageview` on layout so I have to edit problematically. Any ideas ?

**Update :** apparently changing `image.scaleAbsolute(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());` to 
`image.scaleAbsolute(500f, 500f);` or `image.scalePercent(500f);` does the trick (I have to play with the numbers to fit the page). 
    Downside the quality image is horrible...

**PdfUtils**

```
    public static final String LOG_ACTIVITY = "PdfUtils";

public static String ImgPdf(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> listPathImg,String folder, String pdfName) {

    String result ="";
    Image image;
    String path = FileUtils.createFolderApp(folder);
    path = path + pdfName + ".pdf";

    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 38, 38, 50, 38);

    Log.v(LOG_ACTIVITY, "Document Created");

    Rectangle documentRect = document.getPageSize();

    try {

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(path));

        document.open();

        for (int i = 0; i < listPathImg.size(); i++) {

            Bitmap bmp = MediaStore
                    .Images
                    .Media
                    .getBitmap(
                            activity.getContentResolver(),
                            Uri.fromFile(new File(listPathImg.get(i))));

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, stream);

            image = Image.getInstance(listPathImg.get(i));

            if (bmp.getWidth() > documentRect.getWidth() || bmp.getHeight() > documentRect.getHeight()) {

                //bitmap is larger than page,so set bitmap's size similar to the whole page
                image.scaleAbsolute(documentRect.getWidth(), documentRect.getHeight());

            } else {
                //bitmap is smaller than page, so add bitmap simply.
                //[note: if you want to fill page by stretching image,
                // you may set size similar to page as above]

                image.scaleAbsolute(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
            }

            image.setAbsolutePosition(
                    (documentRect.getWidth() - image.getScaledWidth()) / 2,
                    (documentRect.getHeight() - image.getScaledHeight()) / 2);
            image.setBorder(Image.BOX);
            image.setBorderWidth(15);
            document.add(image);
            document.newPage();
        }
        result=path;
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
        result="";
    } finally {
        document.close();
    }

    return  result;
}
```

Comment: There's even a comment in code that tells you what to do to fill the page.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I tried the suggestion didn't help

Comment: You didn't say that you tried that - only that you tried changing border or absolute position.

Comment: Yes sorry. I may have done it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11121655/12472557).

I changed `image.scaleAbsolute(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());` to 
`image.scalePercent(scaler);` ofc you have to include

```
float scaler = ((document.getPageSize().getWidth() - document.leftMargin()
                    - document.rightMargin() - indentation) / image.getWidth()) * 100;
```

Now it fit. Though the image quality is not perfect.

Comment: There's a `scaleToFit` which does roughly the same thing, but without you having to compute it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `image.scaleAbsolute(width,height)` try `image.scaleToFit(width,height)`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is change the size of

```
    Rectangle documentRect = document.getPageSize();
```

Rectangle has 4 parameters that you can set on construction (x , y, width, height).
Changing those might solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: have you tried changing not only the numbers of Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 38, 38, 50, 38); or image.setBorderWidth(15); but also changing PageSize to A0?

Comment: I unfortunatly can't test it out myself because this app doesn't work on my emulator

Answer (score 0):

I use PDF24 Creator if I understand the question correctly.