# iTextpdf : How to add image without changing the image aspect ratio

Tags: java, android, itext

Im using iTextPdf library, and I want to insert image from gallery into pdf in such a way that image width may be resized if its width is larger than document width, else keep its width as it is, (Similarly with the height) **without affecting the aspect ratio of the actual image**.  In simple words, I don't want the image to be stretched.
I started using iTextPdf recently only and not so familiar with it.
I've tried using
`image.scaleAbsolute()`
`image.scaleToFit()`
`image.scalePercent()`
but none of these methods seem to solve my problem since image can have different width and height.
I've been looking for this answer for days but no luck.
I would be happy with any help. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120775/itext-image-resize

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you. Got the answer (answered by `Franz Ebner`) from link provided by @PeterMmm. This is the line that solved my problem:    float scaler =((document.getPageSize().getWidth() - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin()) / image.getWidth()) * 100;
image.scalePercent(scaler);